# Fadeout Div Content - Empty Div Content - Fadein New Content

Tags: javascript, video, fadein, fadeout

I am using onClick functionality for my buttons. My button code looks like this:

```
<a onClick="fadeNext('#myDIV1',500);">Button 1</a>
<a onClick="fadeNext('#myDIV2',500);">Button 2</a>
```

My JS Function looks like this:

```
function fadeNext(selectedId, speed) {

          var containerID = '#imageSwap';
          var vis = ($(containerID + ' div:visible').length > 0) ? $(containerID + ' div:visible').eq(0) : $(containerID + ' div').eq(0);
          var next = $(selectedId);
          vis.fadeOut(speed);

          next.fadeIn(speed);
          }
```

This fades the content correctly and works great, but Video content (Vimeo) still plays when its not visible. Tried this JS, but still no luck:

```
function fadeNext(selectedId, speed) {

          var containerID = '#imageSwap';
          var vis = ($(containerID + ' div:visible').length > 0) ? $(containerID + ' div:visible').eq(0) : $(containerID + ' div').eq(0);
          var next = $(selectedId);
          vis.fadeOut(speed, function() {
              $(this).empty().show();
          });

          next.fadeIn(speed);
          }
```

With this JS, the content no longer fades out or empties.

I'm a JS rookie and having trouble getting the empty() code to work. The main reason for this is that my DIV will be containing videos (Vimeo). When the user clicks to change content, I'd like for the videos to be unloaded, so the video/sound no longer plays.

Any help / advice would be appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing without more code, but I did a quick test and empty() does appear to stop a vimeo video. Checkout this simple jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/judeosborn/9HUmZ/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I've created a jfiddle with my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/umJQ9/8/)

Comment: When I try to add the empty functionality, things go haywire: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/umJQ9/9/) The buttons seem to work fine the first time, but fail to load the new div content on subsequent clicks.

Comment: It seems that once the content is emptied, there's no way to retrieve the content on subsequent requests. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tutanramen/umJQ9/16/

I added a link to an external resource: https://raw.github.com/vimeo/player-api/master/javascript/froogaloop.js

I then gave each iframe an id (v1 and v2 but they are not used in this fiddle) and a class of player.

And then added this to fadeNext:

```
$(".player").each(function() {
    $f($(this)[0]).api("pause");
});
```

Now when you click to select the other video it actually pauses all the videos.